# How to find the previous <div> element from a <div>? using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
<div class="accordion-heading" onclick="$(this).parent().find(&quot;#badge_request_content&quot;).focus();">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        <h4>
            <span class="ex-num complete-num wait_on_type">
                <i class="icon-ok"></i>
            </span>
            <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
            Write a quick summary
        </h4>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
```

Actually i want to find the  tag class name of the previous div as shown above. like `<seconddiv id>.find(previous div span class name)`

Does anyone help on this? i wants to done this with jquery?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Which element are you trying to traverse to, and from what event? Posting your jQuery code here would definitely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```
$('divId').prev('div').find('span').attr('class')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I found the answer with your help

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I found the answer with your help

Answer (score 3):

not sure understand exactly what you want but try something like that

```
$('your div').prev().attr('class')
```

Comment: Yes this was i actually wants to do. Thanks a lot:) i found the same in my own

Comment: Its really helpful to me to come up with some solutions to my work. Thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I found the answer with your help

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I found the answer with your help

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#collapseTwo').on('click',function(){
    var spanClass = $(this).prev('div').find('span').attr('class');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for spend your time on this!!. I found the way how to do with this.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I found the answer with your help

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I found the answer with your help

Answer (score 0):

Use [**prev()**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
var spanclass = $('#collapseTwo').prev().find('span').attr('class');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solutions. With the help of this i could find the solution for my project.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I found the answer with your help

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I found the answer with your help